# How can I delete the lines starting with "//" (e.g., file header) which are at the beginning of a file?

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed

I want to delete the header from all the files, and the header has the lines starting with `//`.

If I want to delete all the lines that starts with `//`, I can do following:

```
sed '/^\/\//d'
```

But, that is not something I need to do. I just need to delete the lines in the beginning of the file that starts with `//`.

Sample file:

```
// This is the header
// This should be deleted
print "Hi"
// This should not be deleted
print "Hello"
```

Expected output:

```
print "Hi"
// This should not be deleted
print "Hello"
```

Update:
If there is a new line in the beginning or in-between, it doesn't work. Is there any way to take care of that scenario?

Sample file:

```
< new empty line >
// This is the header
< new empty line >
// This should be deleted
print "Hi"
// This should not be deleted
print "Hello"
```

Expected output:

```
print "Hi"
// This should not be deleted
print "Hello"
```

Can someone suggest a way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Update: The accepted answer works well for `white space` in the beginning or in-between.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have updated the question.

Comment: Should any empty lines at the start of the file if there are no initial comments be deleted or not?

Comment: Yes, there can be empty line at the start or in-between the header. This is more like a consistency issue. Some cases, there can be space and then `//` in the header.

Comment: Essentially this is what does what you ask `(?m)(?:^\s*//.*\s*){2}` since I'm not familiar with  sed or awk workings I put it in a comment with no explanation. But, if you try anything that does not do this exact functionality, it won't work.

Comment: @Maxt8r among other issues, neither sed nor awk use PCREs so that PCRE won't work in either of them.

Comment: If you can find an engine that does the minimal extended regex, this might be an option `^(\s*\n\s*//.*){2}\n?` or even `^\s*\n\s*//.*\s*\n\s*//.*\n?`  which do not require multi-line mode.

Comment: @Maxt8r `\s` is not specified by POSIX and so not supported by any standard UNIX tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you please try following. This also takes care of new line scenario too, written and tested in https://ideone.com/IKN3QR

```
awk '
(NF == 0 || /^[[:blank:]]*\/\//) && !found{
  next
}
NF{
  found=1
}
1
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply checking conditions if a line either is empty OR starting from `//` AND variable found is NULL then simply skip those lines. Once any line without `//` found then setting variable found here so all next coming lines should be printed from line where it's get set to till end of Input_file printed.

Comment: Almost there! For this updated question, your answer is the one that worked. Will accept it. I was wondering if there is a way to handle `white space` before `//` in the header? I tried your solution after adding space, but did not work.

Comment: @Sweety, could you please try now and lemme know if that helps you?

Comment: You want `/^[[:blank:]]*\/\//` for lines *starting* with a comment, not merely *containing* a comment.

Comment: @glennjackman, sure thank you sir changed regex to as suggested one cheers.

Comment: I changed the "blank line" condition, in case the blank lines contain whitespace.

Comment: Simple and effective ++

Comment: @glennjackman, sure thank you sir for doing so cheers.

Comment: @Sweety, it worked fine for me please check https://ideone.com/IKN3QR once and lemme know then.

Comment: Can you try adding space in this line `<spaces here>      // This is the header`?

Comment: @Sweety,yeah added it and it seems to be working please lemme know if any queries here.

Comment: Last question, how do I do it on multiple files and in place?

Comment: @Sweety, then you need to use gawk latest I believe >=5.1 version of it which gives inplace option in it too, there is nice thread on SO on that you could easily search it in here happy learning cheers.

Comment: Awww, I did not know earlier that with awk, I won't be able to do it on multiple files in place (sad).

Comment: @Sweety, you could either update your gawk version or try to make temp file where take this command output in it and once output successfully gone to it rename  that temp output file to current Input_file you will get plenty of example on here SO, I don't want to confuse users so not editing my answer here cheers.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '1{:a; /^[[:space:]]*\/\/\|^$/ {n; ba}};p' file
print "Hi"
// This should not be deleted
print "Hello"
```

Slightly shorter version with `GNU sed`:

```
sed -nE '1{:a; /^\s*\/\/|^$/ {n; ba}};p' file
```

Explanation:

```
1 { # execute this block on the fist line only
    :a; # this is a label
     /^\s*\/\/|^$/ { n;  # on lines matching `^\s*\/\/` or `^$`, do: read the next line
          ba }           # and go to label :a
};  # end block
p   # print line unchanged:
    # we only get here after the header or when it's not found
```

`sed -n` makes `sed` not print any lines without the `p` command.

Edit: updated the pattern to also skip empty lines.

Comment: This works in GNU `sed`. Any idea what adaptations are necessary to make it work with BSD and/or POSIX `sed`?

Comment: @chepner I'm not sure, but my man page says `-E` and EREs are supported by POSIX?

Comment: I think you have to use BREs for [POSIX `sed`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), but that seems easy to fix (GNU `sed -n '...'` works as long as you escape the `|`). BSD `sed` seems to be the trouble-maker.

Comment: The `\s` is definitely a GNU extension; you can use `[[:space:]]` instead, but that's decidedly less convenient if you know you are using GNU `sed`.

Comment: yeah I was trying to kill two birds with one stone and didn't hit one, I'll leave both versions in there

Comment: @chepner FYI POSIX lets you use ERE constructs by preceding them with ```\``` in a BRE, e.g. `x\{2,3\}` for an RE interval.

Comment: @Lev that first command when run with OSX/BSD sed outputs `sed: 1: "1{:a; /^[[:space:]]*\/\ ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)`, it's probably GNU-only too but idk which constructs make it so. Unfortunately almost any time you try to do more than `s/old/new/g` with sed you're into GNU or other proprietary extensions and/or simply undefined behavior.

Comment: This solution did not work in case of first line being a new line.

Comment: @Sweety on which `sed`? it works fine for me with empty first line.

Comment: I tried your first solution - `sed -n '1{:a; /^[[:space:]]*\/\/\|^$/ {n; ba}};p' file`

Comment: How can I use it for multiple files and in place change?

Comment: I guess it worked with `sed -n -i '1{:a; /^[[:space:]]*\/\/\|^$/ {n; ba}};p' *`

Comment: @Sweety yep, that's the way to do it!

Comment: @Sweety you know there's no such thing as inplace editing right? When you do `sed -i 'script'` it's not editing the file in-place, it's just internally making a copy of the file and overwriting the original with that copy later. You can do the same with any command `cmd` just by writing `in_cmd() { for file; do cmd 'script' "$file" > tmp && mv tmp "$file"; done; }; in_cmd *` Don't sacrifice the tool/script you use over the ability to do "inplace" editing as that's the easy part of any program.

Answer (score 2):

I sounds like you just want to start printing from the first line that's neither blank nor just a comment:

```
$ awk 'NF && ($1 !~ "^//"){f=1} f' file
print "Hi"
// This should not be deleted
print "Hello"
```

The above simply sets a flag `f` when it finds such a line and prints every line from then on. It will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box.

Note that, unlike some of the potential solutions posted, it doesn't store more than 1 line at a time in memory and so will work no matter how large your input file is.

It was tested against this input:

```
$ cat file

    // This is the header

// This should be deleted
print "Hi"
// This should not be deleted
print "Hello"
```

---

To run the above on many files at once and modify each file as you go is this with GNU awk:

```
awk -i inplace 'NF && ($1 !~ "^//"){f=1} f' *
```

and this with any awk:

```
ip_awk() { local f t=$(mktemp) && for f in "${@:2}"; do awk "$1" "$f" > "$t" && mv -- "$t" "$f"; done; }

ip_awk 'NF && ($1 !~ "^//"){f=1} f' *
```

Answer (score 1):

In case `perl` is available then this may also work in slurp mode:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's~\A(?:\h*(?://.*)?\R+)+~~' file
```

`\A` will only match start of the file and `(?:\h*(?://.*)?\R+)+` will match 1 or more lines that are blank or have `//` with optional leading spaces.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i -Ez 's/^((\/\/[^\n]*|\s*)\n)+//' file
```

The `^((\/\/[^\n]*|\s*)\n)+` expression will match one or more lines starting with `//`, also matching blank lines, only at the start of the file.

Comment: This is not what I want. It deletes all the lines that starts with `//` from my file. What I want is: only the header of the file that starts with `//` should be removed and not any other line that starts with `//`.

Comment: @Sweety I updated the answer with a GNU `sed` solution.

Comment: It says `sed: invalid option -- 'z'`

Comment: @Sweety That means your `sed` is not GNU `sed`. I also added matching of blank lines at the start, too.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ed` (the *file* editor that the *stream* editor `sed` is based on),

```
printf '1,/^[^/]/ g|^\(//.*\)\{0,1\}$| d\nw\n' | ed tmp.txt
```

---

Some explanations are probably in order.

`ed` takes the name of the file to edit as an argument, and reads commands from standard input. Each command is terminated by a newline. (You could also read commands from a here document, rather than from `printf` via a pipe.)

1. `1,/^[^/]/` addresses the first lines in the file, up to and including the first one that does *not* start with `/`. (All the lines you want to delete will be included in this set.)
2. `g|^\(//.*\)\{0,1\}$|d` deletes all the addressed lines that are either empty or *do* start with `//`.
3. `w` saves the changes.

Step 2 is a bit ugly; unfortunately, `ed` does not support regular expression operators you may take for granted, like `?` or `|`. Breaking the regular expression down a bit:

1. `^` matches the start of the line.
2. `//.*` matches `//` followed by zero or more characters.
3. `\(//.*\)\{0,1\}` matches the preceding regular expression 0 or 1 times (i.e., optionally)
4. `$` matches the end of the line.